# Retrieving kickstart and other .img file in pxe remote installation in CentOS

Tags: linux, http, dhcp, pxe-boot, tftp

I am trying to installation CentOS through pxe tftp installation. Installation starts but it fails to download image files from the http server. but file are accessible on the http server. Logs from the installing system are following.

```
Unable to retrieve the //abc.com/CentOS6.5/ks.cfg file.
INFO  : transferring //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/updates.img
ERROR : Error downloading //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/updates.img: HTTP response code said error
INFO  : transferring //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/product.img
ERROR : Error downloading //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/product.img: HTTP response code said error
INFO  : transferring //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/install.img
ERROR : Error downloading //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/install.img: HTTP response code said error
```

(above links are http. cannot put links because i'm new here.)

I've tried following solutions that I found on the internet:

- Tried disabling the iptables completely.
- Tried restoring default SELINUX context for /var/lib/tftpboot
- Tried Disabling SELINUX.

Unfortunately there is no http response code available. I've checked all the access logs.

Any suggestion are much appreciated.

Comment: Are you passing correct network information to Anaconda via kernel parameters? If yes then you should boot with some LiveCD and check if the HTTP resource you are trying to download is actually available at that URL from that computer.

Comment: please post the kickstart file (removing any sensitive information). I have always liked this site for kickstarts: http://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Anaconda/Kickstart

Comment: I was booting virtual machine. Looks like the ethernet virtualization did not support booting through pxe. So it used to take ip from dhcp and than could not move ahead. Changing ethernet type solved the problem. Thanks @ Florin Asavoaie and  natxo asenjo for help.

Answer (score 1):

if you are retrieving components by HTTP then I think your urls do not look right.

```
INFO  : transferring //abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/updates.imgerror
```

it seems it should look like

```
INFO  : transferring http://abc.com/CentOS6.5/images/updates.img
```

this means you might have to check the url definition